# Porque no me codifica la contraseña con la funcion btoa()?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Buenas estaba haciendo un ejercicio en que nos pedia que usaramos la función btoa de javascript para codificar el email y la contraseña. Hago un console.log para ver como se muestra el correo y la contraseña codificados pero el único que me lo hace bien es el correo os muestro mi html, el javascript y como me aparece en el log:

```
<input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Introduce Correo" value="<?php if(isset($email)) echo$email;?>" name="email">
<input type="password" id="pwd" placeholder="Introduce Contraseña" name="pswd">

codificarBTOA();
function codificarBTOA(){
  var correo = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var contraseña = document.getElementById("pwd").value;
            
  var codMail = window.btoa(correo);
  var codContra = window.btoa(contraseña);

  var res = "Encoded string: " + codMail + "Encoded pwd :" + codContra;
  console.log("Correo: "+codMail)
  console.log("Contrasenya: "+codContra);
}
```

Y el log en el que contraseña no me hace nada:

```
Correo: d2FpbDU4bXdAZ21haWwuY29t
Contraseña:
```

Comment: pues es que tú le estás poniendo el valor al campo email desde PHP, pero la contraseña está vacía y, cuando se ejecuta tu JS, está vacía. Después no vuelves a ejecutar codificarBTOA nunca más. Ponle un `onChange="codificarBTOA();"` al campo de contraseña... o añade un botón que ejecute ese método cada vez que hagas clic, etc

Answer (score 0):

Por lo general no se usan acentos ni características lingüisticas del castellano para declarar variables, así que recomiendo cambies `contraseña` por `contrasena`

La otra parte es que tu función se estaba ejecutando y no muestra password por que no tiene nada el input de password. Hice un botón para que llenes los campos y pruebes, ya debería funcionar así

```js
function codificarBTOA(){
  var correo = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var contrasena = document.getElementById("pwd").value;
            
  var codMail = window.btoa(correo);
  var codContra = window.btoa(contrasena);

  var res = "Encoded string: " + codMail + "Encoded pwd :" + codContra;
  console.log("Correo: "+codMail)
  console.log("Contrasenya: "+codContra);
}
```

```html
<input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Introduce Correo" name="email">
<input type="password" id="pwd" placeholder="Introduce Contraseña" name="pswd">
<br><br>
<button onClick="codificarBTOA()">Codificar BTOA</button>
```

Comment: Lo que hago es básicamente introduzco un correo y contraseña, y en caso de que la contraseña este mal, pues el input de email muestre el anterior correo y solo tenga que volver a meter la contraseña el usuario. Y me lo ha hecho bien con el tema de mail con el que introduzco, el único problema lo tenia con la contraseña. Pero lo probare gracias !